Count of non-negative solutions to linear diophantine equation
Let $a,b,m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$. I want a formula for the number of non-negative integer solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^2$ to the equation $ax+by=m$. One way to do this is to obtain a particular not-necessarily-non-negative solution $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, use the general formula for all integer solutions
$$(x,y) = (x_0 + bt, y_0 - at), \quad t \in \mathbb{Z},$$
and count how many values of $t$ make this pair non-negative. The result is
$$\#\left(\left[-\frac{x_0}{b}, \frac{y_0}{a}\right] \cap \mathbb{Z} \right) = \left\lfloor \frac{y_0}{a} \right\rfloor - \left\lceil -\frac{x_0}{b} \right\rceil + 1.$$
However, I would like to have a formula that does not depend on computing a particular solution of the diophantine equation, i.e. a formula in which $x_0$ and $y_0$ do not appear. Is there a way to do this?
EDIT: The reason why I suspect there might be such a formula is because if the floor and ceiling functions are removed from the above expression, then we may simplify $\frac{y_0}{a} + \frac{x_0}{b} = \frac{m}{ab}$.
